# Prove that sets of gates $\{CNOT^a, H^b, T^c\}$ are not universal

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, universal-gates

I'm trying to show that none of these sets of gates are universal:

- ${CNOT^2, H, T}$
- ${CNOT, H^2, T}$
- ${CNOT, H, T^2}$

For the first one $CNOT^2$ seems to be the identity gate which means that there's no way this gate set can flip the value of some bits. I'm not sure if this argument is correct/suffices.

For the second one, $H^2$ is the identity gate again(rotation of angle $2\pi$), so now this gate set can only rotate about 1 axis with the $T$ gate hence it's not a universal gate set.

The third one is the one I'm most unsure about. $T^2$ seems to be a rotation of $\pi/2$ about the $z$ axis and that does not seem to cause any problems (eg: $HT^2$) still seems to be a rotation about 2 distinct axes by an angle that's an irrational.

Comment: For the third one, please see the [Gottesman-Knill theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottesman%E2%80%93Knill_theorem).  $T^2=S$, which is a gate in the normalizer of the Pauli group (a Clifford gate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First gate set: only has single qubit gates. The group of single qubit gates is closed under composition. E.g. you can't get to CNOT because it's not a single qubit gate.

Second gate set: only has phased permutations. The group of phased permutations is closed under composition. E.g. you can't get to H because it's not a phased permutation.

Third gate set: only has Cliffords. The group of Cliffords is closed under composition. E.g. you can't get to T because it's not a Clifford.